# How to include an external Javascript to html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Problem: External javascript is not working. 
I want my registration page to be validated and I have written the code but I don't know where to call it I tried the following.

This is my javascript code:

```
var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
var fname = document.form.Name.Value;
var lname = document.form.Last.value;
var fpassword = document.form.password.value;
var frassword = document.form.repassword.value;
var femail = document.form.Email.value;

function submit()
{
   if ( fname === "")
   {
       document.form.Name.focus();
       alert("Please enter the name");
       return false;
   }
   if ( lname === "")
   {
       document.form.Last.focus();
       alert("Please enter last name");
       return false;
   }
   if( fpassword === "")
   {
       document.form.password.focus();
       alert("You can't leave password empty");
       return false;
   }
   if( frassword === "")
   {
       document.form.repassword.focus();
       alert("Please confirm password");
       return false;
   }
   if( femail === "")
   {
       document.form.Email.focus();
       alert("Don't leave Email blank");
       return false;
   }
   else if (!emailRegex.test(femail))
   {
       document.form.Email.focus();
       alert("Not a valid Email");
       return false;
   }
   if( fname !== '' && lname !== '' && fpassword !== '' && frassword !== ''       && femail !== '')
   {
       alert("Registration sucessfull");
   }
}
```

I tried like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="skill.js"></script>
<script>
  submit();
</script>
```

And I tried this too:

```
<form name="form" onclick="submit()">
```

Comment: This should work, is your skill.js file in the same directory as your html file? Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: @DanielJacobson No this will not work. The function will fire when you click anywhere on the form. You need `<form name="form" onsubmit="submit()">`

Comment: Please inlcude your HTML. Do you have a submit button in your form?

Comment: Yea I do have submit button in my html

Comment: But the function is submit() and the button name is "Register" so I guess that does not make a difference

Comment: @Daniel Jacobson yea I have the .js file in the same directory

Comment: @Mikey Is the link to the .js file correct?

Comment: @Vasu_candy Yes it does make a difference, having an onclick event handler on your form will fire when you click the form, not necessarily the submit button. Yes, your link should be correct. However, any typo can make the difference. Make sure your external file is called `skill.js`. Also, I asked about the HTML because that will give us some more insight in your code.

Comment: @Mikey But I just have one button for the whole form and still it does not work. And about HTML Code I tried pasting it here but I was unable to paste it. and my external file name is skill.js and I just want to know if i have linked correctly ?

Comment: @Vasu_candy Yes it is linked correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm... well then what's wrong? There is only one button and I have linked it properly but still I can get that work??

Answer (score 0):

create a `submit` `button` inside the `form` element like this -

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and then add an `attribute` on the opening `form` tag, like this-

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="submit()">
```

make sure you have linked to you JS file already.